# React Native AppState: what is correct / expected behaviour

Tags: ios, react-native, brownfield

In my iOS application 5 tabs. 1 and 4, RN (different) apps, other - native. When you go from RN tab to native - RN view continue to live.
What is correct behaviour of AppState for each RN app - should it say that current state background / inactive, or it should say that RN app is active?